# Linear Regression better than ANN

Tags: neural-networks, scikit-learn

I have dataset with 1000 samples. 250 inputs and 250 outputs. Each input can have on of 23 different discreet values. Each output is a continuous variable.

(it's an engineering structure with 250 structural members, inputs section area, outputs member max stresses)

**PROBLEM:**

Is it possible that a Linear Regression model performs better than an ANN model?

**DATA OVERVIEW:**

left: input right: output

inputs are always scaled before fitting/training/testing

[image]

LINEAR REGRESSION MODEL:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg_pin = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True,
                          normalize=False,
                          copy_X=True)

linreg_pin.fit(X_pin_train, y_pin_train)

LIN REG SCORES:
Train set RMSE score [MPa]:  8.796
Test set RMSE score [MPa]:  12.782
Train set R2 score:  0.768
Test set R2 score:  0.511
```

ANN MODEL:

```
ann_pin = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(70, ), 
                   activation='tanh', 
                   solver='sgd', 
                   alpha=0.01, 
                   batch_size=8, 
                   learning_rate='constant', 
                   learning_rate_init=0.001, 
                   max_iter=1,  
                   shuffle=True, 
                   random_state=None, 
                   tol=0, 
                   verbose=True, 
                   warm_start=True,
                   momentum=0, 
                   early_stopping=False)

ANN MODEL SCORES:
Train set RMSE score [MPa]:  14.27
Test set RMSE score [MPa]: 17.68
Train set R2 score:  0.389
Test set R2 score:  0.065
```

I also tried to search the best number of hidden units in range (5-250) and the result of grid search seems to me very suspicious. It would suggest that something is wrong with the ANN model. Where can a mistake be located?

Comment: Can you clarify what your model statement is? Is it a single independent variable?

Comment: What is the meaning of the images? That does not look like a discrete input... Also, what is the activation function of the network outputs? Why is the `max_iter` parameter of the network set to 1? Why is momentum set to 0?

Comment: @ArunJose could you please explain what do you mean by the model statement?

Comment: y = mx + c --> in linear regression, what is x and y in your case?

Comment: @JanKukacka, meaning of the images, the plot on the left side shows distribution of inputs for each of 250 inputs. Each input can take on of 23 numbers, the biggest possible number is 0.01 the smallest possible number is 0.007. There is no activation function of the network outputs or you can say it is the identity activation. `max_iter=1` because I need more control after each training epoch. That's also why also `warm_start=True`, so `ann_pin.fit(X, y)` starts from last weight vector if i call `fit` method again.

Comment: @ArunJose the relation between X and Y in my data set is probably more complex than y = mx + c. X, in my case, is a vector of 250 inputs standing for section areas of 250 different members and Y is a resulting stress in those members. The stress in members is some function of X. There is a physical model defining relation between X and Y given a full set of input parameters. I'm trying to build a model which takes only a subset of all required input parameters to the physical model and predicts the physical response. Does it help?

Comment: I'm asking what did you finally use as your model when you ran the linear regression. Obviously you gave it the model statement you want to build right? And the 250 outputs is confusing me as well. Info required: how many observations in your data? How many independent variables considered in your regression and neural net.

Comment: I have 1000 observations (data samples) and 250 independent variables (input neurons) and 250 target variables (output neurons) Following the notation of scikit-learn from [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) X [n_samples, n_features]=[1000, 250] y [n_samples, n_targets]=[1000,250]